# change cvs data with python

Tags: python, excel

Hi guys i hope you are doing excellent.

im having some issue with a data base and is because the way they are aligned makes it impossible to generate a report or analyze them

this is an example

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy323.png)

if you see i cant sort it,  t has variable because some rows has no information it doest matther if that rows dissapear

in order to work with the file i need to see it like this

[Result file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jHiV.png)

im sorry im just a front end developer and i have a really hard time with time of issues if some one can help me I will appreciate it

i share the file is not sensitive information

this an example of file csv https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UbhuyUYhQRu68XvqMuiac0nlZhCQoq_t/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is a snippet of code that uses the `pandas` library to get the csv you shared into the format of the second screenshot you shared:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in the csv
df = pd.read_csv('testalan.csv', header=None, names=['Machine', 'TempHeader'])

# Rename the temporary header to the metadata entry in the first row
df.rename(
    columns={
        'TempHeader': df.iloc[0].Machine
    },
    inplace=True
)

# Drop the first row that is now part of the header
df = df[1:]

# Drop all rows missing at least one element
df = df.dropna(axis='rows')

# Transpose the matrix to flip the rows and columns. Could replace df.transpose() with df.T
df = df.transpose()

print(df)
```

If you also want to sort by the bottom row, you could add this line:

```
# Get the name of the 2nd row and sort the columns by the value of that row
df = df.sort_values(by=df.iloc[1].name, axis='columns')
```

And to download the csv:

```
df.to_csv('testalan_sorted.csv', header=False)
```

Edit:

I am assuming that the format of the csv is one row for Machine Name followed by one entry for every attribute of that machine. Here is a block of python code that will parse the csv file based on that assumption and the description you provided in the comments:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the original CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('testalan.csv', header=None)

# Initialize an empty dictionary to store the data
data = {}

# Loop through the rows of the DataFrame
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if '(' in row[0]:
        machine_name = row[0]
        data[machine_name] = {}
    else:
        column_name, column_value = row[0], row[1]
        data[machine_name][column_name] = column_value

# Convert the dictionary to a DataFrame
result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

# Save the result to a new CSV file
result.to_csv('output.csv', index_label='Machine')
```

Edit 2:

This code will allow for duplicate machines. It will append a new row for each machine regardless of how many attributes are defined for that machine:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the original CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('original file.csv - Hoja 1.csv', header=None)

# Initialize an empty dataframe to store the resulting data
result = pd.DataFrame()
machine_name = None

# Loop through the rows of the DataFrame
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if '(' in row[0]:
        # Every time you switch to a new machine, add the current machine to the result set
        if machine_name is not None:
            machine_entries = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({ machine_name: machine_attributes }, orient='index')
            result = pd.concat([result, machine_entries], ignore_index=False)

        # Update the current machine name and clear the machine attributes
        machine_name = row[0]
        machine_attributes = {}
    else:
        column_name, column_value = row[0], row[1]
        machine_attributes[column_name] = column_value

# Save the result to a new CSV file
result.to_csv('output.csv', index_label='Machine')
```

Comment: thanks men i apreciate your time the code create a lot of rows like this [2 rows x 9649 columns] can it be like this ?                                                                                                                                                                                                               Machine Creditos Ganados Carga exitosa Apostado Ganado Jackpot Juegos Jugados Descarga exitosa
AinswJLM_03    (207) $0.03  92.52 126.5 54.15 0 98 20.17
AinswJLM_03    (207) $0.03  92.52 126.5 54.15 0 98 20.17
AinswJLM_03    (207) $0.03  92.52 126.5 54.15 0 98 20.17

Comment: can the exit result be a new csv

Comment: I added the code to export the result as a csv. Can you explain what you mean with your first comment? Do you want to split the result into chunks of 6? i.e. each row has 6 entries?

Comment: The code you shared creates 2 rows x 9649 columns like this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11k-_K9ohTdw1O6mFV4KAcmtqvK0autgOoG7n4-lIYxY/edit?usp=sharing and the result csv has to be like this  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C_oi4Gm1do4T0QhBNuvin9JkYyfUKPqovzd63Z2quXg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I updated my answer with a code snippet that looks more like the second doc you shared. Let me know if that's what you are aiming for

Comment: You are so awesome my friend, you dont know how much you are helping me, this is the current result with the new code https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NBhxo1pY1tuPscJ5YK8PIMjALVJ9hkSiJ3-jxnrtBMM/edit?usp=sharing however for some reason is missing some machines and their values for example in the original file this machine AinswJLM_03    (207) has 23 with values each one but in the result file i can see only one this is the original file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PGCRbuvENfBOfiM5xQvmQXtP8u5SnB4P3lnMXAsXvhI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi there, I updated the code to allow for duplicate entries for one machine name! Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Thanks my friend it worked, i send i big hug you are so awesome.